# Installation of Firefox from Alpine Edge

Tags: alpine-linux

I appear to be missing something when attempting to install Firefox from the Alpine Edge Repository

Firefox (Version 61.0.1-r0) [Repo](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/testing/x86_64/firefox)

*as distinct from installing*

Firefox-ESR (Version 52.8.1-r0) [Repo](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/community/x86_64/firefox-esr)

I perform the necessary repository modification as documented [here](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Include:Upgrading_to_Edge) which causes my repository to look like:

```
http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main
http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community
```

Following up with:

```
apk upgrade --update-cache --available
```

Works fine and does all the necessary pulls.  However, when attempting:

```
apk add --no-cache firefox
```

Returns

> ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
>     firefox (missing):
>       required by: world[firefox]

Which is what I would expect from the non-edge repositories.  I'm sure I'm missing something simple and obvious.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For people who are stumbling upon this question, the 1 line answer is

`apk --no-cache add --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing firefox`

This will create a single 1-time install of firefox using the test repo of the edge branch.

In order to figure out the right link, navigate to the [APK package mirror](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=firefox). and put in a search for Firefox. The branch and repository will be populated and your dockerfiles can be updated accordingly.

Editing of the `/etc/apk/repositories` file will also achieve the same effect.

Comment: I had to add in two repos: testing AND main in order to resolve some dependencies to my /etc/apk/repositories file and it worked well. Much appreciated.

Comment: `ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  firefox (missing):
    required by: world[firefox]`

Answer (score 1):

Try with 
RUN apk add \
firefox-esr

Answer (score 0):

Bah, the apk update line had been commented out in the Dockerfile, working fine against the Edge testing repository now

Answer (score 0):

I found that using alpine 3.11 cuased a lot of issues when trying to install firefox. I updated my dockerfile to use 3.12.1 for alpine (i.e. `FROM alpine:3.12.1`) and added `RUN apk add firefox-esr`. This seemed to solve my issues. Hope this help those who are still having issues.

Answer (score -1):

Just append the testing distro to /etc/apk/repositories:

```
export ALPINE_VERSION=edge
echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/${ALPINE_VERSION}/testing" >> /etc/apk/repositories
apk add --no-cache firefox
```

AFAIK you need to use edge, for latest, alpine v3.11 has firefox-esr v68

Comment: `ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  firefox (missing):
    required by: world[firefox]`

Comment: Nobody has compiled firefox for alpine since v68, By looking at `https://git.alpinelinux.org/aports/`search on firefox it might be possible to port if from the sources.